# Search files(key) in s3 bucket takes longer time

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have 10000 files in a s3 bucket.When I list all the files it takes 10 minutes.  I want to implement a search module using BOTO (Python interface to AWS) which searches files based on user input. Is there a way I can search specific files with less time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the best you can do is filter the results based on a file prefix using [the `prefix` named parameter](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/bucket.py#L216).

Comment: That, or keep a list of the bucket contents in another database (DynamoDB for example) and use that to answer queries.

Comment: Yeah, if you need that information frequently, you should definitely cache it somewhere like DynamoDB rather than performing the LIST operation each time.

Comment: The suggestion to store the keys is sensible (and performant), my answer was purely based on the S3 API and Boto.

Comment: I dont want to create another DB .. so I went with Johns suggestion and it worked fine!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to implement the search...

**Case 1**. As suggested by john - you can specify the prefix of the s3 key file in your list method. that will return you result of S3 key files which starts with the given prefix.

**Case 2.** If you want to search the S3 key which are end with specific suffix or we can say extension then you can specify the suffix in delimiter. Remember it will give you correct result only in the case if you are giving suffix for the search item which is end with that string. 
Else delimiter is used for path separator.

I will suggest you Case 1 but if you want to faster search with specific suffix then you can try case 2

Comment: This is my sample log 20121015/00030662235a41d1/DR_SUCCESS/9204f47e28b646f39aa871556730c96f/1350334249946dr.1.log . Is there a way I can search with DR_SUCCESS which is in the middle?