# how to retrive objects in bucket with 'suffix'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Ruby SDK for AWS:S3. I have files  listed in bucket like below:

```
s3://client1/client_name_delivery1_2013-05-01.txt
s3://client1/client_name_delivery2_2013-05-01.txt
```

There may be many files for particular date. I want to fetch all the files for particular date e.g. for `2013-05-01`. I found prefix option of `objects method` of bucket however did not find something like suffix

How should I fetch files by suffix?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to search by suffix.  You can try using the delimiter to specify your suffix as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904326/search-fileskey-in-s3-bucket-takes-longer-time/12907767#12907767)

The list command is quite inexpensive, but if you find you're calling it all the time, consider creating a local database. (Or re-arranging your keys to be prefixed by the data you need to search for.)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I prefer solving this by getting a list of all the objects from the AWS S3 bucket first and then filtering out unwanted objects to get the desired objects using suffix. In Bash/Shell using AWS CLI, the solution would look like this:

```bash
aws s3 ls s3://[BUCKET_NAME]/[DIRECTORY_NAME]/ --recursive | grep "[SUFFIX]"
```

In your case, it is Ruby so the solution using AWS SDK for Ruby would look like this:

```rb
marker = nil

loop do
  response = s3Client.list_objects_v2(
    bucket: [BUCKET_NAME],
    prefix: [DIRECTORY_NAME],
    marker: marker,
    max_keys: 1000
  )

  response.contents.each do |object|
    next if object.key.end_with?('[SUFFIX]')

    puts object.key
  end

  break unless response.is_truncated

  marker = response.next_marker
end
```

*Note: Don't forget to replace `[BUCKET_NAME]`, `[DIRECTORY_NAME]`, and `[SUFFIX]` in the code snippets mentioned above. Also, it is assumed that you have imported the necessary libraries for AWS SDK and you have created the AWS S3 client after authentication.*